# Query to map columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

The below query gives the output of past score past quarter current score and current quarter.

```
SELECT Greatest(1, Least(5, score))      AS past_score,
       Greatest(1, Least(5, curr_score)) AS current_score,
       current_quarter,
       past_quarter
FROM   (SELECT Round(( 0.4 * normalized_sick_leave ) +
                     ( 0.3 * normalized_total ) + (
                            0.3 *
                                    overall_rating ), 1) AS score,
               Round(( 0.4 * normalized_sick_leave_current ) + ( 0.3 *
                     normalized_total_curr )
                     + (
                     0.3 * overall_rating_curr ), 1)     AS curr_score,
               current_quarter,
               past_quarter
        FROM   (SELECT Nvl(abs_record.duration / 10, 0)                  AS
                               normalized_sick_leave,
                       time_entry.hours / 540                            AS
                       normalized_total,
                       5 - To_number(perf_rating.overall_rating)         AS
                       overall_rating,
                       abs_record_current.duration / 10                  AS
                               normalized_sick_leave_current,
                       time_entry_current.hours / 540                    AS
                               normalized_total_curr,
                       5 - To_number(perf_rating_current.overall_rating) AS
                       overall_rating_curr
                               ,
                       time_entry.quarter
                               past_quarter,
                       time_entry_current.quarter
                       CURRENT_QUARTER
                FROM   abs_record ABS_RECORD,
                       time_entry TIME_ENTRY,
                       perf_rating perf_rating,
                       abs_record_current ABS_RECORD_current,
                       time_entry_current TIME_ENTRY_current,
                       perf_rating_current perf_rating_current
                WHERE  abs_record.person_id(+) = time_entry.person_id
                       AND time_entry.person_id = perf_rating.person_id(+)
                       AND abs_record_current.person_id(+) =
                           time_entry_current.person_id
                       AND time_entry_current.person_id =
                           perf_rating_current.person_id(+)
                       AND time_entry_current.person_id (+) =
                           time_entry.person_id))
```

This gives the output as follows -

| PAST_SCORE | CURRENT_SCORE | CURRENT_QUARTER | PAST_QUARTER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.2 | 4.8 | Q1 | Q4 |

What function can i use to change this to

| SCORE | Quarter |
| --- | --- |
| 1.2 | Q4 |
| 4.8 | Q1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple option is to use your current query as a CTE and extract data you're interested in with `UNION (ALL)`, e.g.

```
WITH
   your_query
   AS
      -- your query begins here ...
      (SELECT GREATEST (1, LEAST (5, score)) AS past_score,
              GREATEST (1, LEAST (5, curr_score)) AS current_score,
              current_quarter,
              past_quarter
         FROM (SELECT ROUND(...)
               FROM ...
              )
      )      
      -- ... and ends here        
SELECT past_score AS score, past_quarter AS quarter FROM your_query
UNION ALL
SELECT current_score, current_quarter FROM your_query;
```